# LED Bulbs won't fit my garage door opener

Tags: led, garage-door-opener

These are the last bulbs in the house that I have not been able to change over to LED.

You might be thinking to yourself, they only turn on for 1 minute, what is the big deal. I've started to notice if both bulbs are plugged in and you run the opener too many times, the opener starts to over heat. No bulbs, and the opener keeps going like the energizer bunny.

I've tried almost every single LED bulb that I've been able to get my hands. And the hole is designed for only this type of bulb unfortunately.

Any Suggestions?

The plate where the bulbs sit is not screwed in, it's welded into the opener. I thought about making the hole bigger, but worry about damaging the opener.

Comment: Are you really saying that two 60W bulbs cause this unit to overheat?

Comment: Yea that's what i'm saying. Is it 100% true? Maybe not. But the fact  of the matter is, I want to put leds in my garage opener.

Comment: I personally would consider opening the unit and re-positioning the bulb holders... do make sure you have isolated the unit before attempting any work...

Comment: @Sickest Please keep comments polite and constructive. For more details, you can see our [code of conduct](https://diy.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Maybe the unit is only rated for 25-40W bulbs and they are electronically switching the bulbs, so there's a self-protection circuit to keep you from using large enough bulbs to blow the electronics.

Comment: you can get LED "piano" bulbs; long tubular bulbs no wider than the screw base.

Comment: be careful with using LED bulbs for garage door openers. Something about the light impacts how the wireless remotes function. You can google it and find out more about it. I put in LEDs in mine and started having random problems with the remotes not working properly. I worked with Chamberlain and it was determined the LEDs were causing the issue. Put back regular bulbs and no issues.

Comment: ill keep that in mind user99045

Answer (score 4):

I do think the opener is named incorrectly - it should be Ambass-a-**door**. But that doesn't affect the solution:

Get an [extender](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Medium-Base-Socket-Extender-R52-02006-000/100356980)

[image: Leviton Medium Base Socket Extender]

IMHO, $2.74 isn't much compared to the hassle of cutting a hole in sheet metal and risking ruining a functional garage opener.

Comment: That doesn't look like it would fit either. The narrow part of the housing is too short.

Comment: Might work.  If his opener is like mine, however, it has a frosted plastic cover which wont fit over the bulb if it sticks out further.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using a hole saw is to use a nibbler.  The shards of metal are larger.and the metal falls on YOUR side of of the hole.

Or use a tin snip and snip a quarter inch out from the hole every quarter inch, producing a set of tabs that can be bent in.  This produces no metal that can short things out.  This doesn't work if the hole has a rolled edge unless you have strong wrists.

Do push them in, however.  The sides of the bulb will push them in for you, but might make removing the bulb difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming they do not fit because the leds flare out a bit more at the bottom and the hole in the with metal panel is not allowing them to go in all the way.

Make the hole bigger. Make a jig out of scrap wood with a holes bigger, Use a hole saw to make the jig, clamp the jig on the unit and use the same hole saw in the jig to cut the metal panel.

Turn off the breaker to the unit and go slow, careful not to plung to deep when you get through the metal.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but pretty risky flinging metal shavings around near a circuit board.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove one of the 60 W bulbs and see how it performs. If you need both sides illumnated, try two 40 W bulbs. Any greater intervention would not be worth the trouble, for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just unscrew **this nut** and remove the white backer plate, leave it off or cut the hole bigger if you want and replace it.

[image]